# Why doesn't modernizr spit out a no-mediaqueries class?

Tags: media-queries, modernizr

I thought it used to just do this out of the box but today I had a bunch of issue with it and had to use this test to get it to put the class in my html

`if(!Modernizr.mq('only all')) {
    jQuery('html').addClass('no-mediaqueries');
}`

Just wondering why I get a huge string of no-somefeature classes added in IE8 but have to specifically test for mediaqueries.

Comment: Do you have the Media Queries test added to your build? http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: Yeah, I did a rebuild when I saw it wasn't working and while surprised I had to specifically select mediaqueries figure Imust've missed it on the last build. That did nothing though.